# android logcat doesn't read the logs every time

Tags: android

I try to read all android logcat records in my app and display them on a listview.
In my code sometimes i can read  the logs but somtimes can't.
if i open logcatactivity i can read all the logs but then i can't read

```
oReadLogTask = new ReadLogTask();
    oReadLogTask.execute();

private class ReadLogTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog oProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        oLogVeriler = new ArrayList<LogCatVeri>();

        oProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LogCat.this, "", "Log loading...");
        oProgressDialog.show();
        oProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        oProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                oSayfaYukleTask.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progUpdate)
    {
        oProgressDialog.setMessage("Log load... " + progUpdate[0] + "/" + progUpdate[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params)
    {
        if (params == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            List<String> progs = new ArrayList<String>();
            progs.add("logcat");
            progs.add("-v");                
            progs.add("time");
            progs.add("*:" + "V");
            logcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(progs.toArray(new String[0]));
            mReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logcatProc.getInputStream()), 1024);
            int LineAdetTum = 0;
            int LineAdetAranan = 0;
            String LogTagAdKucuk = LogTagAd.toLowerCase();
            String line;
            while ((line = mReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                LineAdetTum++;
                publishProgress(LineAdetAranan, LineAdetTum);

                if (!line.toLowerCase().contains(LogTagAdKucuk))
                {
                    boolean ready = mReader.ready();
                    if (!ready)
                        break;
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean ready = mReader.ready();
                    if (!ready)
                        break;
                }

                LineAdetAranan++;
                publishProgress(LineAdetAranan, LineAdetTum);

                LogCatVeri oLogVeri = new LogCatVeri(line, LogTagAdKucuk, LogTagAd);
                oLogVeriler.add(oLogVeri);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e("alogcat", "Log read err" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("alogcat", "Log read err2" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (logcatProc != null)
            {
                logcatProc.destroy();
                logcatProc = null;
            }
            if (mReader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    mReader.close();
                    mReader = null;
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("alogcat", "Stream err", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        if (result)
            ShowRes();
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Log rec err", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        oProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Boolean result)
    {
        super.onCancelled(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}    

public void ShowRes()
{
    mLogEntryAdapter = new LogCatAdapter(this, R.layout.lc_log_cat_list, oLogVeriler);
    mLogList.setAdapter(mLogEntryAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Just read all log till now

```
Log.e("Log", " 111");
Log.e("Log", "222");

    try
    {
        // read
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d *:e");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            log.append(line);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(log.toString());

// clear
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-c"});
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
```